# Binding WPF GridViewColumn to method with parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridviewcolumn, objectdataprovider

I am trying to bind `GridViewColumn` to a method with parameter.

My current XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource RemoteAgents}" Name="lvRemoteAgents" DataContext="">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.ID}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.type}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

ID, name and types are predefined properties of the ItemSource class.
These properties are actually fields of the JSON structure. So instead of binding to the properties I want to access JSON field by the field name. In pseudo-code I would look like this:

```
   <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource RemoteAgents}" Name="lvRemoteAgents" DataContext="">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.GetValue('ID')}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.GetValue('name')}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.GetValue('type')}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I defined **ObjectDataProvider** as

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="GetValue"
        ObjectType="{x:Type local:RemoteAgent}"
        MethodName="GetField">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <system:String>empty</system:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

And now I bind to the **OjbectDataProvider** as follows:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetValue}, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

My problem is how to pass parameter to GetValue function.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this way?

Comment: I won't need to define property for each field in JSON structure. And if JSON changes all I need is to change XAML without touching the code behind.

Comment: How you can achieve this without changing at least method `GetField`?

Comment: To access JSON field is like dictionary return json[fieldName];

Comment: I think it is something artificial but you can make your method `GetField` return `Dictionary` and create a converter which will return `Value` of `Key` passed as `ConverterParameter`.

Comment: That makes sense. On the other hand it would be convenient to access methods with parameters

Comment: Have you tried deserializing the JSON into a typed or anonymous .NET object and binding to it directly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal by writing class that inherits DynamicObject.The method you should override in your implementation is TryGetMember.

Look [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember(v=vs.110).aspx) for example. Generally speaking, you are "mocking up" your function calls into the dynamic objects, and XAML in your case will look like:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value.ID}" />
```

Where Value is path to the instance of your dynamic object.

Another way is using IValueConverter, passing parameter through ConverterParameter.

Asssuming you have added a ValueConverter to your resources, code will look like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value,Converter={StaticRessource myConverter,ConverterParameter=ID}}" />
```

Keep in mind that ConverterParameter is not DependencyProperty, so you cannot bind to it.